# insert value from one table to another through same key

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables. both have one field name is same i.e. `user_id`. One table has data filled like user name. i want to get this user name into other table and show user name on webpage.

For example
Table `a` has `user_id` and `user_name`

Table `b` has `id` and `user_id`

I want `user_name` in table `b` through its `user_id`.

can anyone help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must be new to SQL.  This is a basic `join`:

```
select a.user_name
from TableB b join
     TableA a 
     on a.user_id = b.user_id;
```

I would suggest that you get a basic book on SQL so you can more effectively do the applications you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.user_name ,b.user_id
from a,b where
a.user_id = b.user_id;
```